# Retrieve data using wpdb to use for customizer controls

Tags: theme-development, themes

So I have the following code:

```
add_action('customize_register', 'homepage_sections');
//products
function homepage_sections($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_panel('homepage_sections', array(
        'title'             => 'Homepage Sections',
        'priority'          => '20'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_section('homepage_settings_section', array(
        'title'             =>  'Homepage settings',
        'panel'             =>  'homepage_sections',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('homepage_settings_setting', array(
        'default'           =>  1
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('homepage_settings_control', array(
        'section'           =>  'homepage_settings_section',
        'settings'          =>  'homepage_settings_setting',
        'label'             =>  'Number of sections',
        'description'       =>  'Number of sections in homepage',
        'type'              =>  'number'
    ));


    global $wpdb;
    $sections=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT section_id, section_title FROM vt_homepage_sections;');

    foreach($sections as $key){
        $section_id=$key->section_id;
        $cust_setting_id=$section_id.'_setting';
        $cust_control_id=$section_id.'_control';


        $wp_customize->add_setting($cust_setting_id,array(

        ));
        $wp_customize->add_control($cust_control_id,array(
            'settings'          =>  $cust_setting_id,
            'section'           =>  'homepage_settings_section',
            'label'             =>  'test Control'
        ));
    }
}
```

**Issue**
Everything works fine when i don't use variables which contain a value fetched using $wpdb. Is $wpdb object loaded after customizer framework?

When I use the code above, the customizer objects in context should appear in the customizer panel, however they don't. Would appreciate hints to what's wrong with my code above.

regards,

J

Comment: `$wpdb` is already "good" (initialized and you can use its methods) in your `homepage_sections()`. And your code seems just fine. What error you get?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @SallyCJ. There's no error (even though wp_debug is true. They just don't show up in customizer.

Comment: You may want to use a var_dump and error_log to troubleshoot: `ob_start(); var_dump($sections); error_log('sections = ' . ob_get_clean(),0)`.  This will export the var_dump to your system's PHP log, where you can figure out if $sections really contains what you expect.

Comment: $sections simply returns an array of objects, and each object contains a property with the value of 'section_id' db field.

Comment: Turn on [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/#wp_debug_log) and check `wp-content/debug.log` for any errors relevant to the issue. And what exactly do you mean by "the above customized objects font appear in the customizer panel"? *Show* what you see.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. The text you quotes was a typo which I now fixed. I can provide debug.log output during the weekend as that's when I'll get back to this project. However when I enabled wp_debug, no error was returned in browser (relevant to this issue); will have a look in debug.log as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that there maybe two issues here first it seems that you are not establishing a new instance of a WP_Customize_Control like below and also it is important to remember that you have to give at least the min array items to both the setting and the control or it will not show, you had an empty array in the setting.

you also want to make sure that you are not starting your naming conventions with numbers, so I switched them around below.

Here is some changes to your code that you can try:

```
add_action('customize_register', 'homepage_sections');
//products
function homepage_sections($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_panel(
        'homepage_sections', 
        array(
            'title'             => 'Homepage Sections',
            'priority'          => '20'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_section(
        'homepage_settings_section', 
        array(
            'title'             =>  'Homepage settings',
            'panel'             =>  'homepage_sections',
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_setting(
        'homepage_settings_setting', 
        array(
            'default'           =>  1
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
       new WP_Customize_Control(
          'homepage_settings_control', 
           array(
              'section'           =>  'homepage_settings_section',
              'settings'          =>  'homepage_settings_setting',
              'label'             =>  'Number of sections',
              'description'       =>  'Number of sections in homepage',
              'type'              =>  'number'
           )
        )
    );


    global $wpdb;
    $sections=$wpdb->get_results('SELECT section_id, section_title FROM vt_homepage_sections;');

    foreach($sections as $key) :
        $section_id=$key->section_id;
        $cust_setting_id = 'setting_' . $section_id;
        $cust_control_id = 'control_' . $section_id;


        $wp_customize->add_setting(
            $cust_setting_id,
            array(
                'default'   => '',
                'transport' => 'refresh',
            )
        );
        $wp_customize->add_control(
            new WP_Customize_Control(
                $cust_control_id,
                array(
                    'settings'          =>  $cust_setting_id,
                    'section'           =>  'homepage_settings_section',
                    'label'             =>  'test Control'
                )
            )
        );
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: Problem solved Rudy. Thank you :)

Comment: Your welcome. Thank you.